# BlockUI during a function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, blockui

In a web-app there is a button which call a function. How can I do if I want to insert a blockUI during the operation? Have I do a promise? Where in particular?

```
$scope.eraseDB = function(){
    database.destroylocalDB();
};
```

the function:

```
destroylocalDB: function(){

  localDB.destroy().then(function (response) {        
      //Remove cache
      datacache.dr = [];
      database.initDB();
  }).catch(function (err) { 
      console.log(err);
  });       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked the [Angular BlockUI](http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/)?

Take a look at the [documentation](http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/examples/documentation). After configuration, you will just need to:

```
destroylocalDB: function(){
  blockUI.start(); 
  localDB.destroy().then(function (response) {  
      blockUI.stop();      
      //Remove cache
      datacache.dr = [];
      database.initDB();
  }).catch(function (err) { 
      blockUI.stop();
      console.log(err);
  });       
}
```

**EDIT**:

To do what you want, you would need to change your service to return the promise:

```
destroylocalDB: function(){

  return localDB.destroy().then(function (response) {        
      //Remove cache
      datacache.dr = [];
      database.initDB();
  }).catch(function (err) { 
      console.log(err);
  });       
}
```

So you can:

```
$scope.eraseDB = function(){
    blockUI.start(); 
    database.destroylocalDB().then(function(){
        blockUI.stop();
    });
};
```

I didn't test, but it should work.

Comment: First of all thank you very much. I have a question about your answer. Is there a way to do this in the erase button? I kind of: blockUI...... database.destroylocalDB().then(unblockUI)

Comment: Because I tried but console said: ' cannot read property then of undefined '

Comment: Thank you very very much, +1 useful!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a spinner to block your UI until your background operation is completed. Something like:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-spinner

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and would be better as a comment